# Silverlight: Programmatically open and read XAML file?

Tags: silverlight, parsing, xaml, io

I found how to programmatically parse/load a XAML string by using XamlReader.Load(), however if I were to have a user drag/drop a ".xaml" file onto my Silverlight application, how would I go about parsing that file to a XAML file and reading in the contents as a string to serve up to the XamlReader.Load() method.

Or is there a more efficient/better way through using reflection?

I'd like to allow the user to use a "silverlight for dummies" silverlight designer (within reason) to design a simple control. (i.e. a label and a textbox).
Then save this or export it as a XAML file (or maybe I can simply have them save it as a TXT file?)
Then they'd drop this file into my Silverlight application and it would parse the text into a XamlReader.Load(), then I can add my newly programmatically created object to a listbox.

I have the logic for drag/drop file and for loading up the XAML string, but that middle point of getting the contents of a ".xaml" file is what I'm confusing myself on...

*EDIT*

@nicholas, that's exactly what I went with. I don't know what was going on yesterday but I think I just had a major 'brain-fart'.
This is how I ended up going: (still have some cleanup and refactoring, but this was to test)

```
        IDataObject data = e.Data;
        if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            FileInfo[] files = data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as FileInfo[];

            if (files.Length > 1)
            {
                //TODO
            }
            else
            {
                FileInfo file = files[0];
                extension = file.Extension;
                string xaml = string.Empty;
                using (Stream stream = file.OpenRead())
                {
                    xaml = StreamUtils.StreamToString(stream);
                }
                if (!xaml.IsEmpty())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        myListBox.Items.Add(XamlReader.Load(xaml);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a `Drop` event handler, from which you receive event args with `Data` property, an `IDataObject`. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597425%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you find out how to get a `FileStream` for the dropped file, which you can then load into a string (eg use `StreamReader`) to be parsed by `XamlReader.Load()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly there will be three different steps:

- Parse the content of .xaml file or any type of file into a "string"
  (it can be a .txt file or any other format)
- Use XamlReader.Load() to generate an UI element    out of this string
  from step 1
- Insert the UI element from step 2 to ListBox.Items collection

Does that help?